# rails 4 update boolean using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use the link_to update the is_completed boolean of the task
contact has many tasks.

```
resources :contacts do 
  resources :tasks
end


===============
 create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.date     "due"
    t.boolean  "is_completed", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "contact_id"
  end
========
```

how can do that in the contact/index

Answer (score 0):

```
# in your view
<%= link_to 'make it complete', contact_task(@contact, @task), method: :patch %>

# in your controller
def update
  contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  contact.update_attribute(:is_completed, true)
  # ...
end
```

[update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) has some restriction, alternatively:

```
contact.is_completed = true
contact.save
```